# Laravel GroupBy with Sum added to Object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I searched all other questions before. I have to simple groupBy select and get sum out of column. But how to make 1 query out of this ( without merge ). Possible?

```
$Todo = Todo::selectRaw('sum(estimated_time) as amount')->groupBy('user_name')->get();
$Todo = Todo::get()->groupBy('user_name');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you avoid using any raw SQL statements in Laravel.

If your goal is to get the sum of the estimated duration of all todos for each user, you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

For example you could first query all your users and eager load the todos.

```
$users = User::query()->with('todos')->get();
```

And then you can retrieve the sum of the estimated duration for all todos.

```
foreach($users as $user) {
     $user->totalEstimatedTodoTime = $user->todos->sum('estimated_time')
}
```

If you use the total estimated todo time of a user often. You could even define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

For example in your user model:

```
public function getTotalEstimatedTodoTimeAttribute() {
 return $this->todos->sum('estimated_time');
}
```

Then you can retrieve the value like this:

```
$user->totalEstimatedTodoTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in Model  :

```
public function setXXXAttribute($value)
{
     $this->XXX= Model::where('user_name' , $this->user_name)->sum('estimated_time');
}


public function getXXXAttribute($value)
{
     return $this->XXX
}
```

Comment: In which model?

Comment: write this in  model Todo; after use query `Todo::all()` add column `XXX` in the rows. value is : sum `estimated_time`